# Unable to form Elasticsearch (5.1.1) cluster on AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

I am unable to form a ES cluster between 2 master nodes in EC2 instances. Following is the elasticsearch.yml for the nodes.

```
Node1:
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
cloud.aws.protocol: http
cloud.aws.proxy.host: <Proxy addr>
cloud.aws.proxy.port: <proxy port>
cloud.aws.region: us-east
cluster.name: production-test
discovery.ec2.availability_zones: us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1d,us-east-1e
discovery.zen.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.ec2.tag.Name: <ec2-tag name>
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
#discovery.type: ec2
#discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
http.port: 9205
#network.host: _eth0_, _local_, _ec2_
network.host: <private ip_addr>
#network.bind_host: <private ip_addr>
#network.publish_host: <private ip_addr>
node.data: true
node.master: true
plugin.mandatory: discovery-ec2, repository-s3
transport.tcp.port: 9305
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<private ip_addr of node1>","<private ip_addr of node2>"]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<private ip_addr of node1>:9305", "<private ip_addr of node2>:9305"]    
cloud.node.auto_attributes: true
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: aws_availability_zone
node.name: nodetest1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch/
#path.data: /data/elasticsearch/data/production
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch/
path.conf: /etc/elasticsearch

Node 2:
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
cloud.aws.protocol: http
cloud.aws.proxy.host: <Proxy addr>
cloud.aws.proxy.port: <Procy port>
cloud.aws.region: us-east
cluster.name: production-test
discovery.ec2.availability_zones: us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1d,us-east-1e
discovery.zen.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.ec2.tag.Name: <ec2-instance tag name>
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
#discovery.type: ec2
#discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
http.port: 9205
#network.host: _eth0_, _local_, _ec2_
network.host: <private ip_addr>
#network.bind_host: <private ip_addr>
#network.publish_host: <private ip_addr>
node.data: true
node.master: true
plugin.mandatory: discovery-ec2, repository-s3
transport.tcp.port: 9305
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<private ip_addr of node1>:9305","<private ip_addr of node2>:9305"]
cloud.node.auto_attributes: true
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: aws_availability_zone
node.name: nodetest2
#Paths to log, conf, data directories
```

When both the nodes are started, the following is the log data on both the nodes:

```
[INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [nodetest1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[WARN ][o.e.n.Node               ] [nodetest1] timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s
[INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [nodetest1] publish_address {<private ip_addr of node1>:9205}, bound_addresses {<private ip_addr of node1>:9205}
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [nodetest1] started
[INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [nodetest1] failed to send join request to master [{nodetest}{YcGzQ-4CQtmuuxUGMQJroA}{yuxHmvGPTeK-iw59VTj4ZA}{<private ip_addr of node2>}{<private ip_addr of node2>:9305}{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[nodetest][<private ip_addr of node2>:9305][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: NotMasterException[Node [{nodetest}{YcGzQ-4CQtmuuxUGMQJroA}{yuxHmvGPTeK-iw59VTj4ZA}{<private ip_addr of node2>}{<private ip_addr of node2>:9305}{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}] not master for join request]; ], tried [3] times
```

I have searched many similar issues and tried to apply the fixes but i still have the same result. Is there any fault in the elasticsearch.yml file?

```
curl -XGET <private ip_addr>:9205/_cat/master
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
```

The two node instances are running ES-5.1.1 and are in the same security-group and iam role.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What does your security group look like? Do you have a rule to allow an instance to access other instances within the same group?

Comment: IAM is not currently directly relevant for network access, so you can rule that out (though giving them a role was a wise move).  Dollars to donuts its the security groups, otherwise could be host level firewall or apparmor

Comment: IAM role can be used by the AWS plugin to find other instances. So it is helpful. However the firewall still needs to allow access between instances.

Comment: @datasage, i have both my instances in the same security group which allows all traffic inbound/outbound. But i still get the same output.'[{nodetest}{YcGzQ-4CQtmuuxUGMQJroA}{yuxHmvGPTeK-iw59VTj4ZA}{<private ip_addr of node2>}{<private ip_addr of node2>:9305}{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}] not master for join request]; ], tried [3] times'

Comment: I have 2 questions - 1. i am trying to add a ES-5.1.1 master node to an existing ES-2.4.X cluster where the indices are automatically generated by Logstash-5.X.X. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how shall i proceed?
2. I am trying to auto-scale the environment, so is there a work around for unicast statement - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<private ip_addr of node1>:9305","<private ip_addr of node2>:9305"], as i cannot provide ip_addr of the instances everytime a new instance comes up.